# Query on how to delete the files in external stage after loading the data using snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to automate the process of loading the files from S3 to snowflake using snowpipe. I am able to successfully load the data into tables from S3 using snowpipe but not able to delete the files in S3 that are successfully loaded using snowpipe. I tried using purge option within the copy command but got an error as snowpipe does not support purge option.

Could someone provide inputs on how the file in S3 can be deleted automatically after the data is loaded successfully using snowpipe.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a stored procedure that compares what is in the stage (`LIST STAGE`) to what is in the `SNOWPIPE_USAGE_HISTORY` and then scheduling that stored procedure to run on a set schedule using a `TASK`?  That might be the best way to go.

Comment: Rather than delete the source data files maybe consider implementing S3 features to automatically transfer older files to very low cost storage tiers such as Standard-IA or Glacier. Automatically deleting your source data files will make it tricky to work out where data came from (or what has/has not been loaded) in the event of load issues.